# Mod rewrite on https on Apache is not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Without https the cakephe (version 3x) site is working fine. But with https the images, css, js are not loading(404). Can anyone help on this.

Comment: have you add https redirection code in your htaccess file?

Comment: How are you including the assets? Some examples would be helpful.

Comment: It was Apache settings issue.We were forgot to set the setting for AllowOverride to the corresponding directory. Now it is working fine.